# Execute raw commands in a MongoDb collection from Play 2 using ReactiveMongo and JSONCollection

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

Hi I am using ReactiveMongo and Play, and I would like to be able to run a MongoDB command in a collection.

My collection is declared like that :

```
def thingsJSONCollection : Future[JSONCollection] =
  database.map( connectedDb => 
    connectedDb.collection[JSONCollection]("thingsCollection")
  )
```

The command I would like to execute is declared like that :

```
val commandDocument = Json.obj(
    "geoNear" -> "thingsCollection",
    "near" -> Json.obj(
      "type" -> "Point",
      "coordinates" -> Seq(lon, lat)),
    "spherical" -> true,
    "minDistance" -> 0,
    "maxDistance" -> 5000
  )
```

And finally, here is the code that does not compile :

```
thingsJSONCollection.map{
  collection => collection.runCommand( commandDocument )
}
```

When I try to execute the command, I get a long error message that basically says that `runCommand` does not accept `JsObject` as argument :

```
Error:(618, 57) overloaded method value runCommand with alternatives:
  [C <: reactivemongo.api.commands.CollectionCommand](command: C)(implicit writer: collection.pack.Writer[reactivemongo.api.commands.ResolvedCollectionCommand[C]])reactivemongo.api.commands.CursorFetcher[collection.pack.type,reactivemongo.api.Cursor] <and>
  [R, C <: reactivemongo.api.commands.CollectionCommand with reactivemongo.api.commands.CommandWithResult[R]](command: C with reactivemongo.api.commands.CommandWithResult[R])(implicit writer: collection.pack.Writer[reactivemongo.api.commands.ResolvedCollectionCommand[C]], implicit reader: collection.pack.Reader[R], implicit ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)scala.concurrent.Future[R]
 cannot be applied to (play.api.libs.json.JsObject)
  thingsJSONCollection.map(collection => collection.runCommand(commandDocument))
                                                    ^
```

Could someone help me find the way to execute raw commands in a MongoDB collection from Play using ReactiveMongo, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation about raw command is [available online](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/advanced-topics/commands.html) for the BSON serialization.
It can be adapted for the JSON serialization.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import play.api.libs.json.{ JsObject, Json }

import reactivemongo.play.json._
import reactivemongo.api.commands.Command

def rawResult(db: reactivemongo.api.DefaultDB): Future[JsObject] = {
  val commandDoc = Json.obj(
    "aggregate" -> "orders", // we aggregate on collection `orders`
    "pipeline" -> List(
      Json.obj("$match" -> Json.obj("status" -> "A")),
      Json.obj(
        "$group" -> Json.obj(
          "_id" -> "$cust_id",
          "total" -> Json.obj("$sum" -> "$amount"))),
      Json.obj("$sort" -> Json.obj("total" -> -1))
    )
  )
  val runner = Command.run(JSONSerializationPack)

  runner.apply(db, runner.rawCommand(commandDoc)).one[JsObject]
}
```